# Liquibase: Get content of executed changeset that leads to hashsum mismatch

Tags: liquibase

It might happen that different versions of our application (and with that different changelog files) are running against the same database. With that hash sum mismatches might occur.

Just changing the changeset from a plain sql statement to Liquibase features (e. g. for creating a table) will lead to a hashsum mismatch.

Is it possible to know how the executed changeset looks during execution and persisting in DATABASECHANGELOG as 'executed'? When hash sum mismatches occur I only know the changeset that fails ...

One solution might be to persist the changeset within the DATABASECHANGELOG table... or is there a way back from db entries to changelog?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by  "...Is it possible to know how the executed changeset looks during execution" ?

Comment: I have one changeset which gets executed (on our local system, nothing released yet) the first time and everything works fine. As the development phase is still ongoing there might be a change within the changeset definition. So after these change I will get a ValidationFailedException based on a MD5 hashsum missmatch. I would like to know how the first successfully executed changeset looked like.

Comment: You should not change an already executed changeset. If you have changes (like adding another column) create a new changeset. If you are still in development you can of course also change the changeset but then you should delete all changesets that were previously run and rerun them. (You can btw also edit your question to make it more clear - as an alternative to further explain your question in comments.)

Comment: I know. We never change released changesets. So in short there is no way to get the information how the once executed changeset looks like ... thanks.